# using sed command in substitution

Tags: regex, sed

When I use this command

```
echo jones:Adrian W. Jones/OSD211/555-0123 | sed -e 's=^([^:]*):[^/]*/([^/]*)/.*$=\1:\2='
```

I got: **sed: command garbled: s=^([^:]*):[^/]*/([^/]*)/.*$=\1:\2=**

but when I use this one:

```
echo jones:Adrian W. Jones/OSD211/555-0123 | sed -e 's=^\([^:]*\):[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/.*$=\1:\2='
```

I got: **jones:OSD211**

Why should I escape the `(` in sed?

Comment: I think this is spelled out in the `sed` regular expression documentation. The escaped parentheses in `sed` delimit your captured matches for `\1` and `\2`, etc. If you don't escape them, they're just parentheses and `sed` thinks there's no match groups to correspond to your `\1` and `\2`. So it says your match string is "garbled".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, sed uses BRE. in BRE, `(` is literal `(`, you have to escape it to bring it special meaning (grouping)

p.s. Gnu sed has `-r` option to enable ERE.

Comment: but what I know that \ is used to escape the special meaning of a character ?

Comment: @M_E I do mentioned **BRE** in my answer.  If you check the wiki page of BRE, you will see `In the POSIX standard, Basic Regular Syntax, BRE, requires that the metacharacters ( ) and { } be designated \(\) and \{\}, whereas Extended Regular Syntax, ERE, does not.`